# Why does #submit apply to all buttons?

Tags: 8, forms

I have added a #submit handler to the default submit action on a node edit form:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_app_submit_to_usercart';
```

and it works correctly. But I then add a 2nd submit button as:

```
  $form['actions']['save'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => 'Standard Save',
    '#value' => t('Print and Mail Check'),
    '#button_type' => 'primary',
    '#weight' => 6,
  ];
```

and for some reason the submit handler for the submit button gets run for this button as well. I am sure in my handler I can act depending on which button was pressed; but wondering why I need to do that.

### EDIT

Apparently I am asking the wrong question. From my code above it seems that regardless of which button i click it is still submitting as if the main button is pressed. So question is how can i add another button (I have done this dozens of times in D7 and I thought a few times in D8; so not sure why this isn't working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your submit button a unique and valid `#name` attribute. I don't think it will work if you put spaces in it:

```
$form['actions']['save'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#name' => 'standard-save',
  '#value' => t('Print and Mail Check'),
  '#button_type' => 'primary',
  '#submit' => [
    '_my_module_form_submit',
  ],
];
```

**Submit handler**

```
function _my_module_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus(t('Standard Save button triggered.'));
}
```

Comment: Wow.. that makes everything work as I th9ought it should. Not sure where i saw an example with #name but i see a few places like here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2020-02-19/how-to-add-custom-buttonaction-to-a-specific-content-type where it isn't even mentioned. Thank you for the tip!!